# Delayed UI update when adding items to StackPanel

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-interface

Here is the code for my problem:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle1.Fill = color;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        StackPanel1.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "TestBlock" });
    }
}
```

Of course it takes some time for the TextBlocks to be added to the StackPanel. But for some reason the rectangle's layout is updated at the same time as the StackPanel. I tried solving this problem by forcing the rectangle to update with

```
Rectangle1.UpdateLayout();
```

before the TextBlocks are added to the StackPanel. But that did not work, either. So how can I change the color of the rectangle BEFORE it starts to add items to the StackPanel?

I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

`UpdateLayout` has no effect if the Layout didn't change, which is your case.

What you need to call is `InvalidateVisual`. However this is not a very good practice.
I would rather change the Fill in `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.

XAML :

```
 <Button MouseLeftButtonDown="PreviewChangeRectangle" ...>
```

C# :

```
private void PreviewChangeRectangle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 Rectangle1.Fill = color;
}
```

Comment: I cannot find a `PreviewMouseDown` event for my button. And there is no `Rectangle1.InvalidateVisual`, either. What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I noticed that. ;)
When I use the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event it does not change the color, but it works with the `GotFocus` event. Actually I want to perform both actions as soon as the user hits the button (GotFocus), which I did not say in my question. So I would need two separate `GotFocus`-like events for filling the rectangle on the one hand and for performing other actions on the other hand. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

to add to @MBen's comment, my understand is that Virtual Tree is only rendered once all processing is complete

you can spawn a thread or use threadpool and then call dispater to say fill the rectangle and then within for loop use dispatcher to add the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

WPF won't draw anything until you yield to the message pump. The easiest way to do this is to use async/await.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle1.Fill = color;
    await Task.Yield();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        StackPanel1.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "TestBlock" });
    }
}
```